# Indexing in Neo4j

Tags: java, indexing, neo4j

I'm wonderring what's a better approach when needing to have multiple indecies based on some node type or field.
For example, let's say I want to have a graph of students and want to index them by their school and id.

As I understand I can have an index per school like this:

```
// add student
Index<Node> index = this.graphDb.index().forNodes(schoolName);
Node node = this.graphDb.createNode();
node.setProperty("id", studentId);
index.add(node, "id", studentId);

// get student
Index<Node> index = this.graphDb.index().forNodes(schoolName);
Node node = index.get("id", studentId).getSingle();
```

I can on the other hand use one index and do something like:

```
// add student
Index<Node> index = this.graphDb.index().forNodes("schools");
Node node = this.graphDb.createNode();
node.setProperty("id", studentId);
index.add(node, schoolName + ":id", studentId);

// get student
Index<Node> index = this.graphDb.index().forNodes("schools");
Node node = index.get(schoolName + ":id", studentId).getSingle();
```

What is a better approach?
Any advantages to one over the other?
Especially performance wise or storage wise, when there are a lot of nodes involved.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is perfectly valid.
If you want to query all students of a school you can use:

```
Iterable<Node> pupils = index.query(schoolName + ":*");
```

You can also just add both fields to the index:

```
index.add(node, "schoolName", studentId);
index.add(node, "id", studentId);
```

and then query them by a combined query

```
Iterable<Node> pupils = index.query("schoolName:"+schoolName + " AND id:"+id);
```

The first one is smaller in index size but the second one is more powerful.
Performance wise it won't make such a big difference (but you can test it and report back).

You could also use an structure in the graph where a school is a node and the pupils are attached to it by a `LEARNS_AT` relationship which can also have a `start` and `end` temporal property, so it is easier to model your domain. See this [demo graph](http://console.neo4j.org/?init=(1)%20%7B%22name%22%20%3A%20%22MIT%22%7D%0A(2)%20%7B%22name%22%3A%22you%22%7D%0A(3)%20%7B%22name%22%3A%22me%22%7D%0A(1)%3C-%5B%3ALEARNS_AT%5D-(2)%20%7B%20%22start%22%20%3A%2019980101%2C%20%22end%22%20%3A%2020053112%20%7D%20%0A(1)%3C-%5B%3ALEARNS_AT%5D-(3)%20%7B%20%22start%22%20%3A%2020000101%7D%20%0A&query=start%20school%3Dnode(1)%20match%20school-%5Br%5D-pupil%20return%20school%2Cr%2C%20pupil%0A&no_root=true)

Comment: Oh wow, a console! Thanks for that, wasn't aware of it's existence. I'm very new with this, I'll check it out.